# Reference member of class by string and/or enum

Tags: swift

Not sure if I'm asking this question properly or not. But basically I want to reference a member of a class by a string value and/or enum

For example I have the following.

```
var total:Int = 0
if locale.currencyCode == "JPY" {
    for item in Cart.items {
        total += item.fabric.price.JPY * item.quantity
    }
}else{
    for item in Cart.items {
        total += item.fabric.price.USD * item.quantity
    }
}
subtotalAmountLabel.text = "\(total.formatMoney())"
```

But, I'd like to write something like the following instead.

```
var total:Int = 0
for item in Cart.items {
    total += item.fabric.price[locale.currencyCode]* item.quantity
}
subtotalAmountLabel.text = "\(total.formatMoney())"
```

Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary instead.

```
// this should be the declaration of item.fabric.price
let prices = [
    "JPY": <some price>,
    "USD": <some price>,
    // and so on
]
```

Then you can use a string to access it:

```
if let price = item.fabric.prices[locale.currencyCode] {
    // ...
} else {
    // If execution ever reaches here, that means there is no price available in that currency.
}
```